# Problem with datagridvieew in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to add a datagridview in vb.net, but it does not allow me to change the connection string or the database that should be imported to connect to it. The only thing that I'm seeing is the previous ms sql database that I connected with datagridview and everytime I click the new connection, the window closes and it leaves me with the datagridview with the previous connection that I have.

And its not applicable because, now I want to connect it with mysql. Not ms sql.
Its some sort of a cache like feature in vb.net, how do I get rid of it. so that I can add the new connection for mysql?

Do I need to reinstall visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the XSD for your datasource from the solution and then remove the bindings to the DataGridView in your forms formx.designer.vb file.

Probably not the best way of achieving what you want and it will need a little bit of tidying up in the code, but should do the trick.